# What types of things is Tezos doing to improve scalability?

Tags: scalability

In this [recent article](https://ambcrypto.com/tezos-co-founder-arthur-breitman-says-side-chains-are-tricky-and-difficult/), it suggests that Arthur Breitman is not a fan of layer 2 solutions. I don't consider the website of this article to be exactly 'reputable' and I tried searching for where this info about Breitman's opinion originated but found nothing.

I did find a [document by Stephen Andrews](https://docs.google.com/document/d/18hKJnKB8sAZ_fpiHTzj-HJwbQu_SrqOAisjI3IqdM0A/edit#) giving a description of how a layer 2 on Tezos would work and how it would speed up current TPS rates.

And I also found an [older article from Breitman](https://hackernoon.com/scaling-tezo-8de241dd91bd) describing how SNARKS can be a great tool for increasing scalability.

The information seems to counterpose each other.

What things is the Tezos community currently working on to improve scalability?

Comment: "Which way is Tezos headed?" questions with no technical content do not seem useful to me here. Are you asking an authority figure to chime in, or for speculation about the future? I suggest that rephrasing the question not to be multiple choice, while removing the incitement to speculate or dictate, might help to reveal a useful on-topic question. I would upvote some technical questions about scalability, ZK, and/or layer 2, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your well-articulated suggestions Tom. I will update the question/wording and try to improve it. I'm not interested in speculation or dictate, but would like someone in-the-know to chime in. I understand things may be in flux of course. To be fair though, your paraphrasing of my question chopped off the technical part of my question. (Perhaps this isn't the best forum for this question, but where else to ask? TG has become noisy. Maybe Riot?)

Comment: @Tom - If you feel this type of question is not appropriate on TSE, feel free to close or delete it. But then could you please advise on the best channel to ask this question on?

Comment: I won't vote to close, maybe someone can answer. The new question seems to have a clear set of (non-technical) answers -- things various people are actually doing -- and the question is "about Tezos" in some sense.

Comment: I think the topic of the question is ok. It is just the formulation.

Comment: @Ezy, I agree with you and Tom both. After reading it (particularly the original), it felt almost kinda tabloid-ish. Sorry about that. I tried to improve it a bit, but since I'm not actually looking in the code (yet), but looking at it for a business use case, this question is at best only semi-technical.